# FilePath Not Getting Zip

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i would like to zip the multiple files in the folder , however my code below was working but its not zip the files and im not sure what goings on as it getting null value . Kindly advise

```
private static string filepath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AConvert"])
    ? "" : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AConvert"];

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string zipFileName;
    string fileExt;

    try
    {
        fileExt = Path.GetExtension(filepath);
        zipFileName = filepath.Replace(fileExt + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMyy"), ".zip");
        using (ZipOutputStream s = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(zipFileName)))
        {
            s.Password = "ABC123";
            s.SetLevel(4); // 0 - store only to 9 - means best compression

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(filepath));
            entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
            s.PutNextEntry(entry);

            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filepath))
            {
                int sourceBytes;
                do
                {
                    sourceBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    s.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
                } while (sourceBytes > 0);
            }
            s.Finish();

            s.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception during processing {0}", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error/exception? What is it?

Comment: there is no error but the FileExt was null . Is that wrong ?

Comment: are you getting a value for filepath when entering the function ?

Comment: yup ... its getting value of "D:\Report"

Comment: you can't call Path.GetExtension for a directory path,

Comment: huh ? what should i do ? i mean i need to make it select inside the folder of Report all files into zip. Kindly advise Thanks you

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you can upgrade .NET framework, then upgrade to 4.5. It has Zip classes of its own. That are quite simple to use. Avoid third party,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys , its working right now . here the code that i amend from the Kjartan. Thanks

```
private static string filepath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AConvert"]) ? "" : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AConvert"];
    private static string ZipPath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathZip"]) ? "" : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathZip"];


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var yourListOfFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(filepath);

        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            foreach (string filePath in yourListOfFilePaths)
            {
                zip.AddFile(filePath);
            }
            zip.Save(ZipPath + "\\Batch" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyy") + ".zip");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your input is here, but I suspect you might want to use [Path.GetFileName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [Path.GetExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx).

You are currently just getting an empty string, since "D:\Report" does not have an extention.

Furthermore, I believe you would have to do this for each file in the directory, and not just for the directory as a whole, if you want to zip the files that way.

Personally I would recommend you take a look at the [dotnetzip library](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) instead. It has some brilliantly simple ways to create zip-archives and add files to it. In your case, basically something like:

```
var yourListOfFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(pathToYourDir);

using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    foreach(string filePath in yourListOfFilePaths)
    {
        zip.AddFile(filePath);
    }
    zip.Save(pathToTargetDir + "\\MyZipFile.zip");
}
```

**PS:** You can find more [C# examples for DotNetZip here](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples).

Comment: Hi , i downloaded the dll and inserted into the reference however its doesn't show that the zip file appear ., as i put zipfile zip = new zipfile()) with error

Comment: @JaydenNg Make sure you've imported it using `using Ionic.Zip;` at the top of your class.

Comment: that's cool kjartan , thanks ..
May i know where the path after zip ? as i run the code its working but the zip file gone. Kindly advise

Comment: I think it will save it to the directory your application is currently running in, but not quite sure. You can replace `MyZipFile.zip` with a full path though, and save it wherever you like (I'll update my answer).

Comment: Hi Kjartan , what i mean is i dint see the zip file through the directory although i change it to : zip.Save("Batch" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyy") + ".zip");

Comment: Then a file Batch22012015.zip should be found in the directory that your running application is located in, or perhaps in it's bin directory or something? Perhaps you want to replace "Batch" with something like `c:/my_batches/Batch`?